# LLVM -- how to get a pointer into an array of double contained inside a struct?

Tags: llvm

I'm getting either an assertion firing below `IRBuilder<>::CreateBitCast()` (for which I don't know what the point of it is) or if avoiding this call I'm getting an assertion firing below `IRBuilder<>::CreateGEP()`.

I'm trying to get an IR representation of

```
template<std::size_t SIZE>
struct CDer
{   double m_ad[SIZE];
};

template<std::size_t SIZE = 3>
CDer<SIZE> mult(const CDer<SIZE>&_r0, const CDer<SIZE>&_r1)
{   CDer<SIZE> s;
    s.m_ad[0] = _r0.m_ad[0]*_r1.m_ad[0];
    for (std::size_t i = 1; i < SIZE; ++i)
        s.m_ad[i] = _r0.m_ad[i]*_r1.m_ad[0] + _r0.m_ad[0]*_r1.m_ad[i];
    return s;
}
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "llvm/ADT/ArrayRef.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Verifier.h"

using namespace llvm;

static constexpr std::size_t SIZE = 3;

StructType*CreateStruct(LLVMContext& _r)
{   Type *const doubleTy = Type::getDoubleTy(_r);
    auto *const pArray = ArrayType::get(doubleTy, SIZE);
    return StructType::create("DualNumber", pArray);
}

Value* MultiplyDualNumbers(IRBuilder<>& rBuilder, Value* const _pX, Value* const _pY)
{
    LLVMContext& rContext = rBuilder.getContext();
    auto const pDualNumberType = CreateStruct(rContext);

    // Get pointers to the data arrays of the input dual numbers.
    Value* const pX = rBuilder.CreateBitCast(_pX, PointerType::getUnqual(pDualNumberType->getPointerTo(0)));
    Value* const pY = rBuilder.CreateBitCast(_pY, PointerType::getUnqual(pDualNumberType->getPointerTo(0)));

    // Extract the value and derivatives of the input dual numbers.
    Value* const pXValue = rBuilder.CreateLoad(
        pDualNumberType,
        rBuilder.CreateGEP(
            pDualNumberType,
            pX,
            rBuilder.getInt32(0)
        )
    );
    Value* const pYValue = rBuilder.CreateLoad(
        pDualNumberType,
        rBuilder.CreateGEP(
            pDualNumberType,
            pY,
            rBuilder.getInt32(0)
        )
    );

    //Type* const dualNumberType = StructType::get(rContext, {Type::getDoubleTy(rContext), Type::getDoubleTy(rContext), Type::getDoubleTy(rContext)});
    Value* const pResult = rBuilder.CreateAlloca(pDualNumberType);


    Value* const pRetValue = rBuilder.CreateFMul(pXValue, pYValue);
    rBuilder.CreateStore(
        pRetValue,
        rBuilder.CreateGEP(
            pDualNumberType,
            pResult,
            rBuilder.getInt32(0)
        )
    );
    for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {   Value* const pXDer = rBuilder.CreateLoad(
            pDualNumberType,
            rBuilder.CreateGEP(
                pDualNumberType,
                pX,
                rBuilder.getInt32(i)
            )
        );
        Value* const pYDer = rBuilder.CreateLoad(
            pDualNumberType,
            rBuilder.CreateGEP(
                pDualNumberType,
                pY, 
                rBuilder.getInt32(i)
            )
        );
        // Compute the value and derivatives of the product.
        Value* const pDer = rBuilder.CreateFAdd(
            rBuilder.CreateFMul(
                pXValue,
                pYDer
            ),
            rBuilder.CreateFMul(
                pXDer,
                pYValue
            )
        );
        rBuilder.CreateStore(
            pDer,
            rBuilder.CreateGEP(
                pDualNumberType,
                pResult,
                rBuilder.getInt32(i)
            )
        );
    }
    return pResult;
}

int main(int, char**) 
{
    LLVMContext sContext;
    Module sModule("example", sContext);
    IRBuilder<> sBuilder(sContext);
    auto const pDualNumberType = CreateStruct(sContext);

    // Define a function that multiplies two dual numbers.
    auto const pMultiplyType = FunctionType::get(
        pDualNumberType,
        {   pDualNumberType,
            pDualNumberType
        },
        false
    );
    auto const pFunction = Function::Create(
        pMultiplyType,
        Function::ExternalLinkage,
        "multiply",
        sModule
    );
    auto const pBB = BasicBlock::Create(
        sContext,
        "entry",
        pFunction
    );
    sBuilder.SetInsertPoint(pBB);
    const auto pImpl = MultiplyDualNumbers(
        sBuilder,
        &*pFunction->args().begin(),
        &*std::next(pFunction->args().begin())
    );
    pImpl->print(errs());
    sBuilder.CreateRet(pImpl);
    verifyFunction(*pFunction);
}
```

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 0):

There were various problems:

1. function was defined as accepting two arguments of type value of `pDualNumberType` but the code attempted to interpret this as a pointer
2. As in C it is not possible to return an plain array from a function (as chatgpt told me), despite it is being accepted by the library.